# Opencart If Product Has Attribute PHP Statment

Tags: php, opencart

On my product.tpl in Opencart, I am trying to display a "Warranty Included" icon.

My problem is, every product on my store doesnt have a Warranty, only specific Products do. On each of my products I have a whole list of Attributes (Specifications). I was wondering if there was some PHP code that I could wrap around the image that I would be able to use an IF statement to say something like this:

**Single Statement:**

`<?php if (products attributes "Product type = Computer") { 
     //Do this 
 } ?>`

**Multiple Statement:**

`<?php if (products attributes "Product type = Computer" & "Screen Size = 56") { 
    //Do this 
} ?>`

I know thats not the code above, but I was wondering if there was away to use PHP if statements with Opencart Attributes.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: basically: figure out which opencart functions returns those attributes, or lets you look up a specific one. e.g. `if($cart->getAttribute('warranty') == true)`, or whatever it really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 :** (Dirty method)

```
if ($attribute_groups) {
  foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { 
    foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { 
      if($attribute['name']=='warranty' && $attribute['text']=="yes")
      {
        // display image
        // stop the loop if you don't need it further
      }
     }
  }
}
```

**Method 2** : create a function in `model/catalog/product.php` like `checkProductWarranty()` which may return a Boolean value

In this method basically you need to join tables `product_attribute` and `attribute_description` on `attribute_id` put `name="warranty"` in where clause and do your thing

for reference you can see `public function getProductAttributes($product_id)` in the same model file

Method 1 works but it will loop through all attributes which might not be efficient thing to do

Comment: I Love method one! That's exactly what I was looking for... Is there a way I can ALSO make so I can use two if statements. So it has to have two attibutes exact before it displays the image? like `if($attribute['name']=='warranty' && $attribute['text']=="yes") AND ($attribute['name']=='Screen Size' && $attribute['text']=="55")`

Comment: make two if statements one below the other `if(warranty conditions) { $warrantyFound = true;} if(screen conditions) { $screenSize =attribute['text'];}` then after all these foreach loops use `if($warrantyFound && $screenSize="55") { //do something }`